# Solve this integral by the FTC (complex FTC?)

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

$$\int_{\gamma} ze^{-z} dz$$ where ${\gamma}$ is the unit circle centered at the origin.

By Cauchy's Theorem it is the composition of functions analytic in C and so is analytic on and inside ${\gamma}$, therefore it is equal to 0.

But I'm looking for how you would answer this question using the FTC?

Edit: fixed the question

Comment: Just look for an indefinite integral of $ze^{-z}$.

Comment: This looked like a typo to me.  Maybe $\displaystyle\int_\gamma \Big( f(z)=ze^{-z} \Big)\;dz$ would have been clear, even if perhaps unprecedented.

Comment: Fixed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any smooth parametrization $\gamma(t)$, $t\in[0,1]$. Then
$$
\int_{\gamma} ze^{-z} dz=\int_0^{1}\gamma(t)e^{-\gamma(t)}\gamma'(t)\,dt=\left.e^{-\gamma(t)}-\gamma(t)e^{-\gamma(t)}\right|_0^{1}=0
$$
since $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$.

Comment: But how can you say it has an anti-derivative...dont you have to prove it has an anti-derivative before you can make your statement?

Comment: It depends on what the symbol $\int_\gamma f(z)dz$ means to you. The way I understand it, the first equal sign is the definition. After that, I have a usual Riemman integral: $$\int \gamma(t)e^{-\gamma(t)}\gamma'(t)dt=\int ue^{-u}du=e^{-u}-ue^{-u},$$ with $u=\gamma(t)$.

Comment: But the second equal sign can't be automatically valid? Some functions mightn't have an anti-derivative. That's why it seems to me that I should have to prove a function has an anti-derivative before I can apply your statement?

Comment: You lost me there. If you differentiate $e^{-u}-ue^{-u}$ you get $ue^{-u}$, so the former is an antiderivative of the latter. And, in any case, any continuous function has an antiderivative, whether you can write it as an explicit formula or not.

Comment: ok ty, i have to get my head around it.